# List all files used by a shell script

Tags: unix, scripting

I have a ksh script, which calls many other scripts. These scripts further has execute statements pointing to many more scripts and uses many more config files. If all these scripts and config files aren't present in the same folder, then how can I find the name and location of each script executed and config file used when the primary script is executed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `strace` utility to track system calls made by a process and it's children.

For example, given this simple script which accesses a file within the same directory and a file elsewhere on the system:

```
$ cat strace-test.sh
#!/bin/sh
cat local-file.txt > /dev/null
cat /etc/issue > /dev/null
```

Here's the output of running strace on an execution of that script:

```
$ strace -q -f -t -e trace=openat bash strace-test.sh
01:42:10 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
01:42:10 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
01:42:10 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
01:42:10 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
01:42:10 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/tty", O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK) = 3
01:42:10 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
01:42:10 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 3
01:42:10 openat(AT_FDCWD, "strace-test.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
[pid 24729] 01:42:10 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
[pid 24729] 01:42:10 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
[pid 24729] 01:42:10 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
[pid 24729] 01:42:10 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
[pid 24729] 01:42:10 openat(AT_FDCWD, "local-file.txt", O_RDONLY) = 3
[pid 24729] 01:42:10 +++ exited with 0 +++
01:42:10 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=24729, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
[pid 24730] 01:42:10 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
[pid 24730] 01:42:10 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
[pid 24730] 01:42:10 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
[pid 24730] 01:42:10 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
[pid 24730] 01:42:10 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/issue", O_RDONLY) = 3
[pid 24730] 01:42:10 +++ exited with 0 +++
01:42:10 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=24730, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
01:42:10 +++ exited with 0 +++
```

Within that output are two lines documenting the expected file access:

```
...
[pid 24729] 01:42:10 openat(AT_FDCWD, "local-file.txt", O_RDONLY) = 3
...
[pid 24730] 01:42:10 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/issue", O_RDONLY) = 3
...
```

Of course, in a real script doing real work, you'll have much more output to look through. That's where `grep` comes in to help with searching through it.

```
$ sh -c "strace -q -f -t -e trace=openat bash strace-test.sh" 2>&1 \
  | grep openat \  # only match lines that include "openat"
  | grep -v -E '(.so|/usr/lib|/dev)'  # exclude lines that match 
                                      # "uninteresting" files
[pid 22711] 15:02:35 openat(AT_FDCWD, "local-file.txt", O_RDONLY) = 3
[pid 22712] 15:02:35 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/issue", O_RDONLY) = 3
```